# Remove an apache alias subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm using Apache 2 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I added an alias for a subdirectory, to point to gitweb. I realised I should probably make it accessible only on https - so I removed the alias and **restarted Apache**.

I can still navigate to `http://xyz/gitweb` - even with no alias in any of my config files. How do I remove it?

**EDIT**

The config file looked like this before:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/administrator/webroot
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/administrator/webroot/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /gitweb/ /usr/share/gitweb/
        <Directory /usr/share/gitweb/>
                Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                AllowOverride All
                order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AddHandler cgi-script cgiDirectory
                Index gitweb.cgi
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this after:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/administrator/webroot
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/administrator/webroot/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you reload apache? Can you provide config file?

Comment: As mentioned in the question - I restarted apache. There's no hint of the alias in the config file now. so there's not much to provide, but I've added what I did to the question

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at page cached by your browser?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I thought of that too. I switched browsers, and even tried another PC. It's definitely still live.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot.

The gitweb installer had added a file to /etc/apache2/conf.d/ that added the alias.

Thanks all for looking.

Anyone who as similar weirdness, check that folder for unexpected configs.

Comment: Something like this can help find such problems too: `sudo find /etc/apache2 -type f -exec grep -Hin Alias {} \;` Replace the `"Alias"` keyword with any one of the keywords supported by the Apache2 modules to find whether a setting is set here or there.